# OpenGL - load Triangles from padded array

Tags: opengl, rendering

i try to port some code from the old fixed function pipeline to new rendering.
I have triangles defined like this (pseudo-code):

```
struct TriangleMesh
{
   float[3] normal1;
   float[3] vert1;
   float[3] vert2;
   float[3] vert3;
   byte[2] padding;
}
```

And then i have an array of these, having 50 bytes for each triangle in there.

I want to load and render these triangles.

Is that possible without restructuring the data?

I can load it with `GL_BufferData`, then i know i have to bind a VAO and use `GL_VertexAttrribPointer` to tell Opengl how a single Vertex looks like.

BUT:
I have a larger "superstructure" here, by having the data grouped into 3 vertices, with a normal and padding around. Can i somehow tell opengl to respect that?

Because in my understanding, VertexAttribPointer works "for each vertex" and not for a whole triangle at once?

Also, my vectors are not normalized. But in my understanding, i need to normalize all vectors with respect to the largest/smallest one in that dimension, not each vector individually (so that the whole model at the end fits into the cube spanning from [0,0,0] to [1,1,1]).

Can i use the vertex shader to do that, or what is the way to do that?